# OpenMP recursive tasks with shared data results in a huge slowdown

Tags: c, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I am trying to implement a n-queens solver with OpenMP tasks. However, the game board is set in main function and I am giving it to a function.

So far, I have is:

```
bool solve_NQueens(int board[N][N], int col) 
{ 

    if (col == N) 
    { 
        // #pragma omp critical
        //     print_solution(board);
        #pragma omp critical
            SOLUTION_EXISTS = true;
        return true; 
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    { 
        if (can_be_placed(board, i, col)) 
        {  
            int new_board[N][N];
            board[i][col] = 1; 
            copy(board, new_board);
            #pragma omp task firstprivate(col)
                solve_NQueens(new_board, col + 1); 
            board[i][col] = 0;

        }
    }

    return SOLUTION_EXISTS; 
}
```

The initial call to this function in the `main` is:

```
    #pragma omp parallel if(omp_get_num_threads() > 1)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp taskgroup
            {
                solve_NQueens(board, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Parameters:

```
// these are global
#define N 14
bool SOLUTION_EXISTS = false;
// these are in main
int board[N][N]; 
memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
```

Compiler:

```
gcc
```

Number of threads: `4`

I used `taskgroup` to wait all tasks before getting the result and I had to copy the game board for each task (which is a hard job when `N` is set to 14 since there are 356k solutions).

I tried to make board `firstprivate` or `private`, use `taskwait` inside and outside of the loop, use `taskgroup` inside the for loop and so on. I need some advice to optimize this logic.

Note: putting a `taskgroup` in the for loop under the `if` clause also helps, but this is much slower than expected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a huge issue in your code: solve_NQueens can submit the tasks recursively and *return before all the tasks are actually completed*. You need to put a synchronization before the `return` so the value of `SOLUTION_EXISTS` will be valid (using either a `#pragma omp taskwait` or a `#pragma omp taskgroup`).

In terms of performance, there is multiple issues.

The main problem is that to many tasks are created: you create a task in *each* recursive call. While creating few tasks bring the needed parallelism, creating to much of them also introduces a significant overhead. This overhead can be much higher than the execution of the tail calls. A *cut-off* strategy to can be implemented to reduce the overhead: the general idea is to create tasks only for the first recursive calls. In your case, you can do it with a clause `if(col < 3)` at the end of the `#pragma omp task`. Please note that `3` is an arbitrary value, you may need to tune this threshold.

Moreover, `board` is copied (twice) during the task creation (since it is a static array and default variables required by an OpenMP task are implicitly copied). Your additional copy is not needed and the line `board[i][col] = 0;` is useless *if the code is compiled with the OpenMP support (otherwise pragma are ignored and this is *not* true*). However, the additional overhead introduced should not be critical if you fix the problem described above.

Comment: thank you for the advice. But I do not think that I get you correctly in the last part. What do you mean by copied twice? How should I fix it? I tried firstprivate(board) but it did not work.

Comment: Because I need to check the other states that I can put in a column, so that is why I wrote board[i][col] = 0

Comment: The last part is not the very important. The array is copied twice because you first make a copy of the arry yourself and then OpenMP will make another copy implicitly. Why did `firstprivate(board)` did not work? Which version of gcc do you use?

Comment: gcc 7.4.0, I guess it is because the parameter passing style, it just passes the reference to the initial board object. That is why when I make 'board[i][col] = 0'  then solutions consist all zeros

Comment: GCC should not pass a reference regarding the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) (see page 86, 182 and 27). If it does, it is probably a bug of GCC, and in this case, the result of your code can be wrong because the task can be executed after the loop. If you want to be safe, you could allocate `new_board` dynamically yourself and use `shared(new_board)` (but it can slow down your program a bit). You should not forget to free the arrays *after* the task has been executed or in the task themselves.